# How to force apach don't remove port if it exists?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have following url

```
http://localhost:1234/cat1/cat2?path=value&param2=val2
```

and following rules:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} path=([^&]*)&(.*)
 RewriteRule cat2    cat2/%1.html? [R=301]
```

result:

```
http://localhost/cat1/cat2/value.html
```

expected result:

```
http://localhost:1234/cat1/cat2/value.html
```

How to correct my rules to achieve it?

**P.S.** for *HTTP_HOST* without port it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

Set ServerName localhost:1234 or don't leave it up to mod_rewrite to decide where to redirect to in your substitution.  Normally rules of this type do not redirect at all, just change the path internally.

Example of providing the entire URL in the substitution: `http://%{HTTP_HOST}/...`

If your client sent a host header including the Port #, it will be accounted for in HTTP_HOST.